# Subdirectory and domain multisite installation

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains, domain-mapping

I have this structure:

http://example.com/

http://example.com/site2

http://example.com/site3

http://example.com/site4

...

Now, I want http://example.com/site4 to be http://mycampaignwebsite.com/

A redirect is not a solution, neither a new installation (data is shared over the network using `switch_to_blog()`)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ seems outdated. I'm using version 4.1

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you say that the Domain Mapping plugin "seems outdated"? Its last update was on Dec. 7th, which was a month and a half ago as I write this. It also lists "Automattic" as one of the members of its development team, which I generally take as a good sign.

Comment: Doh! My mistake. I read "Compatible up to: 4.0.1". I am going to test. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Even if it's only *tested* up to 4.0.1, it will most likely be fine with 4.1. (If it said *Compatible to 2.5*, I'd probably be more worried.) Good luck!